# Jquery dropdown not working right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was creating a dropdown with jquery, HTML and CSS. I want to close the dropdown when the user clicks outside of dropdown. But it's not working fine.

JS

```
function _drpdntest() {
 $(".drpdn-click").click(function(){
var _drpdn_container = $(this).attr("data-drpdn-click"); 
var _drpdn_content =  $('[data-drpdn-content="'+_drpdn_container+'"]');
_drpdn_content.toggleClass("drpdn-show"); 
_drpdn_content.siblings().removeClass("drpdn-show");
$(document).click(function(event){
_drpdn_content.removeClass("drpdn-show"); 
});
$(this, _drpdn_content).click(function(event){
event.stopPropagation();
});
});
}
// Run Component Function
$(document).ready(function(){
_drpdntest();
});
```

HTML

```
<button class="drpdn-click" data-drpdn-click="main">CLICK</button>
<div class="drpdn-content drpdn-body" data-drpdn-content="main">
Main
</div>
```

CSS

```
.drpdn-content {
z-index: 1000;
position: absolute;
display:none;
overflow: hidden;
}
.drpdn-content.drpdn-show {
display: block;
}
```

Comment: When i run your code and click outside it hides again. so seems to work just fine

Comment: it not show when i click for the first time. and i don't want to hide the when the user clicks on dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have not added `stopPropagation()` for button click. Due to which on button click it is triggering document click.

Also `$(this, _drpdn_content)` should be `$(_drpdn_content, this)` or simply remove this while adding `stopPropagation`.

Here second parameter provides context in which selector search will get performed, in short second parameter is `parent` and you are saying to search all `childs` matching with selector provided in first parameter.

```js
function _drpdntest() {
  $(".drpdn-click").click(function(e) {

    var _drpdn_container = $(this).attr("data-drpdn-click");
    var _drpdn_content = $('[data-drpdn-content="' + _drpdn_container + '"]');

    _drpdn_content.siblings().removeClass("drpdn-show");
    _drpdn_content.addClass("drpdn-show");
    $(_drpdn_content).click(function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(document).click(function() {
      _drpdn_content.removeClass("drpdn-show");
    });
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
}
// Run Component Function
$(document).ready(function() {
  _drpdntest();
});
```

```css
.drpdn-content {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.drpdn-content.drpdn-show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="drpdn-click" data-drpdn-click="main">CLICK</button>
<div class="drpdn-content drpdn-body" data-drpdn-content="main">
  Main
</div>
```

Comment: dropdown hides when i click on the content area. sorry not working

Comment: Welcome @RishiThakur, Happy to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you want, based on what you said in the comment

It now shows on the first click, and it doesn't hide when you click on the option.

```js
function _drpdntest() {
  $(".drpdn-click").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this)
    var _drpdn_container = $(this).attr("data-drpdn-click");
    var _drpdn_content = $('[data-drpdn-content="' + _drpdn_container + '"]');
    _drpdn_content.toggleClass("drpdn-show");
    $(document).click(function(event) {
      if (event.target != $this[0] && event.target != _drpdn_content[0]) {
        _drpdn_content.removeClass("drpdn-show");
      }
    });
    $(this, _drpdn_content).click(function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
  });
}
// Run Component Function
$(document).ready(function() {
  _drpdntest();
});
```

```css
.drpdn-content {
  z-index: 1000;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.drpdn-content.drpdn-show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="drpdn-click" data-drpdn-click="main">CLICK</button>
<div class="drpdn-content drpdn-body" data-drpdn-content="main">
  Main
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure tbh, but did it fix the problems your facing?